Splitting a string that is delimited by multiple delimiters (regex)
My data is structured like this:
df <- data.frame(SampleID = c(
  "Akt.B.M_1867_1:100", "Akt.B.M_1869_1:100", "Akt.B.M_1871_1:100",
  "Akt.B.M_1878_1:100", "M.M.K_1259_1:100",   "M.M.K_1262_1:100",
  "M.M.K_1264_1:100",   "M.M.K_1272_1:100",   "SKO.Shard_30_1:100",
  "SKO.Shard_32_1:100", "SKO.Shard_45_1:100", "Zh.San_618_1:100",
  "Zh.San_624_1:100",   "Zh.San_629_1:100"
))

I would like to extract the characters in front of the first period and the characters surrounded by the underline and place them into two subsequent columns.  I tried to use separate_wider_delim but there are some entries that have one period and some entries that have two periods.  How would I do this in separate_wider_regex or is there a better way without using this function?
Thanks

1) separate_wider_regex Using the input in the Note at the end use separate_wider_regex as shown:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate_wider_regex(SampleID, c(A = "[^.]*", "\\..*_", B = ".*", "_.*"), 
    cols_remove = FALSE)

giving
# A tibble: 14 × 3
   A     B     SampleID          
   <chr> <chr> <chr>             
 1 Akt   1867  Akt.B.M_1867_1:100
 2 Akt   1869  Akt.B.M_1869_1:100
 3 Akt   1871  Akt.B.M_1871_1:100
 4 Akt   1878  Akt.B.M_1878_1:100
 5 M     1259  M.M.K_1259_1:100  
 6 M     1262  M.M.K_1262_1:100  
 7 M     1264  M.M.K_1264_1:100  
 8 M     1272  M.M.K_1272_1:100  
 9 SKO   30    SKO.Shard_30_1:100
10 SKO   32    SKO.Shard_32_1:100
11 SKO   45    SKO.Shard_45_1:100
12 Zh    618   Zh.San_618_1:100  
13 Zh    624   Zh.San_624_1:100  
14 Zh    629   Zh.San_629_1:100  

2) sub Using base R remove everything after the first dot giving A and then match everything to the underscore, capture to the next underscore and match the rest keeping the capture.
transform(df, 
  A = sub("\\..*", "", SampleID),
  B = sub(".*_(.*)_.*", "\\1", SampleID)
)

Variations of this are possible:
# 2a - this variation uses the same regex for both A and B
pat <- "([^.]*).*_(.*)_.*"
transform(df, 
  A = sub(pat, "\\1", SampleID),
  B = sub(pat, "\\2", SampleID)
)

# 2b - this variation uses trimws to simplify the regexes needed
transform(df, 
  A = sub("\\..*", "", SampleID),
  B = trimws(SampleID,, "[^_]") |> trimws(, "_")
)

# 2c - same but use Reduce to iteratively apply trimws
trimws2 <- function(x, y) trimws(x,, y)
transform(df, 
  A = sub("\\..*", "", SampleID),
  B = Reduce(trimws2, init = SampleID, c("[^_]", "_"))
)

# 2d - use scan to avoid needing regular expressions
Scan <- function(x, ...) scan(text = x, what = "", quiet = TRUE, ...)
transform(df,
  A = Scan(SampleID, comment.char = "."),
  B = Scan(SampleID, sep = "_")[c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)]
)

3) separate_wider_delim If we replace the first dot with underscore then we can use separate_wider_delim
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(tmp = sub("\\.", "_", SampleID)) %>%
  separate_wider_delim(tmp, names = c("A", NA, "B", NA), delim = "_")

4) strsplit Using Base R use strsplit to split the elements of SampleID by dot and underscore and then take the first and second last of each such vector.
L <- strsplit(df$SampleID, "[._]")
transform(df,
  A = sapply(L, head, 1),
  B = sapply(L, \(x) tail(x, 2)[1])
)

5) strcapture With Base R use strapture to extract the matches to the capture groups in the regular expression.  pat is from (2).
transform(df, part = strcapture(pat, SampleID, list(A = "", B = "")))

Note
df <- data.frame(SampleID = c(
    "Akt.B.M_1867_1:100", "Akt.B.M_1869_1:100", "Akt.B.M_1871_1:100",
    "Akt.B.M_1878_1:100", "M.M.K_1259_1:100", "M.M.K_1262_1:100",
    "M.M.K_1264_1:100", "M.M.K_1272_1:100", "SKO.Shard_30_1:100",
    "SKO.Shard_32_1:100", "SKO.Shard_45_1:100", "Zh.San_618_1:100",
    "Zh.San_624_1:100", "Zh.San_629_1:100"
  )
)


very nice! similar to what I posted

@G.Grothendieck I used the separate_wider_delim.  It worked great.  However, how would I edit the separate_wider_regex to add anther column "C = 1:100".  In other words the string after the last underscore.  I'm still figuring out regex.

Try df %>%   separate_wider_regex(SampleID, c(A = "[^.]*", "\\..*_", B = ".*", "_", C = ".*"),      cols_remove = FALSE) or
df %>%   mutate(tmp = sub("\\.", "_", SampleID)) %>%   separate_wider_delim(tmp, names = c("A", NA, "B", "C"), delim = "_")

Let's go by parts, like Riemann:
You would like to:

Extract the characters in front of the first period
And the characters surrounded by the underline
Place them into two subsequent columns

library(tidyr)

# your data

df <- data.frame(SampleID = c(
  "Akt.B.M_1867_1:100", "Akt.B.M_1869_1:100", "Akt.B.M_1871_1:100",
  "Akt.B.M_1878_1:100", "M.M.K_1259_1:100",   "M.M.K_1262_1:100",
  "M.M.K_1264_1:100",   "M.M.K_1272_1:100",   "SKO.Shard_30_1:100",
  "SKO.Shard_32_1:100", "SKO.Shard_45_1:100", "Zh.San_618_1:100",
  "Zh.San_624_1:100",   "Zh.San_629_1:100"
))

# regex for the desired extraction

df <- df %>%
  extract(
    SampleID,
    into = c("Prefix", "Middle"),
    regex = "^([^\\.]+)\\..*?_(\\d+)",
    remove = FALSE
  )

df

Output:
             SampleID Prefix Middle
1  Akt.B.M_1867_1:100    Akt   1867
2  Akt.B.M_1869_1:100    Akt   1869
3  Akt.B.M_1871_1:100    Akt   1871
4  Akt.B.M_1878_1:100    Akt   1878
5    M.M.K_1259_1:100      M   1259
6    M.M.K_1262_1:100      M   1262
7    M.M.K_1264_1:100      M   1264
8    M.M.K_1272_1:100      M   1272
9  SKO.Shard_30_1:100    SKO     30
10 SKO.Shard_32_1:100    SKO     32
11 SKO.Shard_45_1:100    SKO     45
12   Zh.San_618_1:100     Zh    618
13   Zh.San_624_1:100     Zh    624
14   Zh.San_629_1:100     Zh    629

First regex
^([^\\.]+):
^: Start of the string.
([^\\.]+): All characters up to the first period.
\\.: Exclude the period.
Second regex
.*?_(\\d+):
.*?: Everything up to the underscore.
(\\d+): Captures the digits after the underscore.

I edited the df so that it does not produce a "wrong comma" error

This is a great primer on regex, thanks!

You can try sub along with read.table
> cbind(df, read.table(text = sub("([^.]+).*_(.+)_.*$", "\\1,\\2", unlist(df)), sep = ","))
             SampleID  V1   V2
1  Akt.B.M_1867_1:100 Akt 1867
2  Akt.B.M_1869_1:100 Akt 1869
3  Akt.B.M_1871_1:100 Akt 1871
4  Akt.B.M_1878_1:100 Akt 1878
5    M.M.K_1259_1:100   M 1259
6    M.M.K_1262_1:100   M 1262
7    M.M.K_1264_1:100   M 1264
8    M.M.K_1272_1:100   M 1272
9  SKO.Shard_30_1:100 SKO   30
10 SKO.Shard_32_1:100 SKO   32
11 SKO.Shard_45_1:100 SKO   45
12   Zh.San_618_1:100  Zh  618
13   Zh.San_624_1:100  Zh  624
14   Zh.San_629_1:100  Zh  629

